# How I can change learning rate of RLlib training agent in dynamic

Tags: ray, learning-rate

I'm using ray RLlib library to train multi-agent Trainer on the 5-in-a-row game. This is zero-sum environment so I have a problem of agents behavior degeneration (always win for 1'st agent, 5 moves to win). I have an idea to change learning rate of the agents in a that way: first train the first agent, left second as random with learning rate equal to zero. After first agent learns how to win more than 90% games switch. Then repeat
But I can't change learning rate after its initialization in constructor. Is this possible?

```
def gen_policy(GENV, lr=0.001):
    config = {
        "model": {
            "custom_model": 'GomokuModel',
            "custom_options": {"use_symmetry": True, "reg_loss": 0},
        },
        "custom_action_dist": Categorical,
        "lr": lr
    }
    return (None, GENV.observation_space, GENV.action_space, config)

def map_fn(agent_id):
    if agent_id=='agent_0':
        return "policy_0"
    else:
        return "policy_1"

trainer = ray.rllib.agents.a3c.A3CTrainer(env="GomokuEnv", config={
        "multiagent": {
            "policies": {"policy_0": gen_policy(GENV, lr = 0.001), "policy_1": gen_policy(GENV,lr=0)},
            "policy_mapping_fn": map_fn,
            },
        "callbacks":
            {"on_episode_end": clb_episode_end},


while True:
    rest = trainer.train()
    #here I want to change learning rate of my policies based on environment statistics
```

I've tried to add these lines inside while True loop

```
new_config = trainer.get_config()
new_config["multiagent"]["policies"]["policy_0"]=gm.gen_policy(GENV, lr = 0.00321)
new_config["multiagent"]["policies"]["policy_1"]=gm.gen_policy(GENV, lr = 0.00175)

trainer["raw_user_config"]=new_config
trainer.config = new_config
```

it didn't help

Comment: Hi, this may not do exactly what you want but do have a look at `lr_schedule`. Usage will be something like: `config={"lr_schedule": [[0, 0.1], [400, 0.000001]],})`

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the same question and did some research on the RLlib implementation.

From the testing scripts it looks like the lr_schedule is given by an interval like

```
lr_schedule: [
            [0, 0.0005],
            [20000000, 0.000000000001],
        ]
```

After that I checked out the implementation details.
In [ray/rllib/policy/torch_policy.py](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/e968b52cb7de4e6c2fcc6e7d5ccb98d984745715/rllib/policy/torch_policy.py) the function *LearningRateSchedule* implements the entry point.
When a lr_schedule is defined the *PiecewiseSchedule* is used.

From the implementation of *PiecewiseSchedule* in [ray/rllib/utils/schedules/piecewise_schedule.py](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/e968b52cb7de4e6c2fcc6e7d5ccb98d984745715/rllib/utils/schedules/piecewise_schedule.py)  follows:

```
endpoints (List[Tuple[int,float]]): A list of tuples
                `(t, value)` such that the output
                is an interpolation (given by the `interpolation` callable)
                between two values.
                E.g.
                t=400 and endpoints=[(0, 20.0),(500, 30.0)]
                output=20.0 + 0.8 * (30.0 - 20.0) = 28.0
                NOTE: All the values for time must be sorted in an increasing
                order.
```

That means the learning rate schedule consists of two parameters:
timestep t (int) and suppost learning rate (float)

For each timestep in-between those values an interpolation is used.
The interpolation can be specified inside the function *PiecewiseSchedule* through the parameter **interpolation** which defaults to **_linear_interpolation**

```
interpolation (callable): A function that takes the left-value,
                the right-value and an alpha interpolation parameter
                (0.0=only left value, 1.0=only right value), which is the
                fraction of distance from left endpoint to right endpoint.
```

**TL;DR;**

Therefore the lr_schedule describes the support points of the linear interpolation (using the default interpolation).

Additionally to change the parameter during the training from this [Github Issue](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/5609) the best choice seems to reinitialize the trainer:

```
state = trainer.save()
trainer.stop()
#re_initialise trainer
trainer.restore(state)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the simple examples here a little confusing. So I wanted to add a clear answer.
To ensure that other users don't have to look into the code I added an issue and wanted to add my answer here:
https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/15647

This is a tested example for a linear decreasing learning rate until a certain point.

```
lr_start = 2.5e-4
lr_end = 2.5e-5
lr_time = 50 * 1000000
config = {
    "lr": lr_start,
    "lr_schedule": [
        [0, lr_start],
        [lr_time, lr_end],
    ],
}
```

[image: lr]